# Redirect user to custom error page when mod_rewrite is disabled

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am redirecting all the request to index.php?q=.. with htaccess file. However, in order for this to work, the user needs to have mod_rewrite enabled for apache. How can I link the user to a custom error page when they don't have mod_rewrite enabled (as I can't use the mod_rewrite functionallity obviously)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 403 your_custom_error_page.php
</IfModule>
```